# select2 with tag and accented letters

Tags: jquery-select2, cpu-word

In my Project I use select2 version 4.0.13.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="arguments[]" id="arguments" multiple="multiple">
  </select>
</div>
```

and the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
        tags: true
    });

});
```

It works good without accented words but for accented words it doestn' work:
For example if my tag is **à** is ok, it works,  but if I write **sarà** it returns **sar`a**; no way to put the accent under the letter.
I tried with chrome and also firefox but the result is the same.
If I remove `tags: true`  from the js part it works.

Comment: is there an alternative framework?

Comment: Someone else posted this issue on the select2 GitHub but it has been closed - https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5684 . You can try the solution here https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5684#issuecomment-605849983 even though it is not ideal.